# Android Bluetooth CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED not fired

Tags: android, bluetooth, connection

I'd like to monitor Bluetooth CONNECTION STATE (note that I'm NOT speaking about adapter ON/OFF state). As I read [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#ACTION_CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED), I can use something like that to get connection status:

```
IntentFilter filter_2 = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED);
registerReceiver(bluetoothConnectionState, filter_2);
```

In theory, I should be able to get the connection states in my BroadcastReceiver by checking the value of `BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_CONNECTION_STATE`. But guess what? `android.bluetooth.adapter.action.CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED` is never fired so I don't get anything. That upsets me a lot, as I can't otherwise say if connection between the devices is established. I have registered receiver and have this permissions in Manifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
```

It's worth noting that I don't have such problems with adapter state and I simply replicated steps, but still, it doesn't know. I'll be glad for any help, maybe someone had similar problem? Thanks!

Comment: What android version? I noticed this no longer works on Pixel 8.0/8.1